# Eigenpairs Differential equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the linear system $Y'=AY$ given by $$Y'=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 2 \\ -9 & -6\end{bmatrix}Y$$

> A. Compute the eigenpairs for the coefficient matrix $A$

So far I have $\lambda = 0\text{ and }-3$ and

> B. For each eigenpair in (A), form a solution of $Y'=AY$.

Which when I used $0$ for my lambda and I substitute $x_1=1$ and then once I compute for my $x_2=-\dfrac{3}{2}$

> Then I I used $x_1=1$ and then my $x_2=3$ resulting to forming my $y(t)=c_1[1, -3/2]+ c_2e^{3t} [-1,3]$
>
> C. Is the set of solutions found a fundamental set of solutions?Justify.

I'm not sure how to justify this.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

$\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}~~3&~~2\\-9&-6\end{bmatrix}$

Part a: You should get an Eigensystem as follows:

$\lambda_1 = -3, v_1 = (-1, 3)$

$\lambda_2 = 0, v_2 = (-2, 3)$

Lets add the details for how we arrived at this first eigenvector.

$A - \lambda_1 I = 0$, yields: $\begin{bmatrix}~~6&~~2\\-9&-3\end{bmatrix}.v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} $

The Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form (RREF) for this is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}~~1&~\frac{1}{3}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} $$

So, we have: $\displaystyle a + \frac{1}{3} b = 0, ~~\text{choose}~~ b = 3 \rightarrow a = -1$.

Part b: To write the general solution, we have distinct eigenvalues and one of them is zero, so we get:

$$y(t) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 v_2 = c_1 e^{-3t}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix}-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}.$$

For Part c, you need to show that $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are two solutions to the DEQ and that the Wronskian$(y_1,y_2)(t) \ne 0$.  Then the two solutions are called a fundamental set of solutions.

You should get $W(y_1(t), y_2(t)) = -9 c_1 c_2 e^{-3 t} \ne 0$ for any $t$.

You can work the rest out and look up the theory since you probably discussed in class.

Comment: No I have initial conditions. And how did you get the the v1, to not be a fraction? What number did you substitute for your x1?

Comment: Wait a second why did you rref it? What I did was plug in my lambda's back into the matrix and subtracted from my a and d. And I meant no I dont have any initial conditions.

Comment: After you do $[A-\lambda I]v_1 =0$, there are MANY ways to solve the system (inverses, solving for one equation at a time, RREF...).

Comment: Ok. I'm not use to rref for the eigenpair, it kind of caught me off guard. Sorry! So then how would I justify C?

Comment: I don't have a y1(t) or y2(t) to show that the wronskian does not equal 0, so would that mean that I do not have fund. set of sol.?

Comment: Oh ok I'm sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: So it would be a fundamental sol because the Wronskian would equal 9e^(-2t), which does not =0

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure if I needed to put the constants or not. Thank you AGAIN!You are awesome!!!

Comment: I have noticed that you have posted several questions, but not upvoted any answers or accepted any answers. You should really pay attention to that. Just some friendly advice.

Comment: Nice discussion leading to the target. =1

Comment: @BabakS.: thank you my friend, I hope things have calmed down for you so you do not make yourself ill! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti I am not quite sure how to upvote...

Comment: No that made it very clear for me. I will go and do a few upvotes then. Thank you.

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti. Nice feedback! +

Comment: @amWhy: Happy Saturday. Whew, just finished a nice nonlinear problem at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381621/nonlinear-differential-equation-thats-separable . Hope you are having a great day! Very busy putting final touches on two different talks for this month and had two last month while working full time! Thanks