# Nonlinear Differential Equation that's separable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $y'=|y|$.

- a) Is the equation linear or nonlinear? Is it separable? Justify.
- b) what do you observe when you solve the two initial value problems $y'=|y|$, $y(0)=1$ and $y'=y$, $y(0)=1$?
- c) what do you observe when you solve the two initial value problems $y'=|y|$, $y(0)= -1$ and $y'=y, y(0)= -1$?

For a), I said it was a first-order nonlinear D.E. and that it is separable and I justified it by saying it can be rewritten in the form of $y'= \sqrt{y^2}$.

How would I solve for b and c, can I get a thorough explanation please

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: Could u help me solve this @Amzoti

Comment: Please see my answer. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to do a slightly different analysis to see if we can study more details of this problem. I will leave it to you to finish off the problem as everything you need is in this writeup.

- The equation is nonlinear (you should state why)
- It is separable (it is asking you to justify that)

What if we wrote:

$$y' = |y| \rightarrow \frac{dy}{|y|} = dt$$

If we integrate both sides, we get:

$$  (\text{sgn}~y) \ln y+ c_1 = t + c_2$$

WLOG, I am going to combine constant terms into a single term, yielding:

$$\tag 1 (\text{sgn}~y) \ln y = t + c$$

What impact does the [*sgn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) term have on the solution of $(1)$?

- Case 1: If $y$ is positive, we get:

$$\ln y = t + c \rightarrow y(t) = c e^{t}$$

- Case 2: If $y$ is zero, we get:

$$y(t) = 0$$

- Case 3: If $y$ is negative, we get

$$-\ln y = t + c \rightarrow y(t) = c e^{-t}$$

What happens to each of those solutions as $t \rightarrow \infty$? It is clear that for negative $y$, we approach zero, for $y = 0$, we have a trivial (critical) fixed point and for positive $y$, we approach $\infty$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

Lets look at a phase portrait (my software defines everything in terms of $x$, so please excuse that) that superimposes the direction fields (green) and actual solutions (blue) curves for many initial values and see if that is the case. Notice how curves from $-y$ all approach zero for any initial condition, curves $y = 0$ are a fixed point and curves from $+y$ all approach $\infty$ as we suspected from the analysis above.

[image]

What if we used the definition of absolute value to rewrite the differential equation as:

$y' = 
\cases{
~~~y  & \text{if } ~~y\ge 0\cr
-y & \text{if } ~~y\lt 0
}$

Now, you should be in a better position to handle the remaining portions of the question.

Comment: Awesome!! Busy, you are! So long as you enjoy what you do... ;-)

Comment: $\large{+1}\Large{+1}$

Comment: @BabakS. Thank you my friend! Hope all is well and have a great day!

Comment: @Amzoti: ARe u on? I have a question about Laplace. I want to know under which conditions the Laplace Transformation of $f$ is unique. I f you know that I will be grateful to sign me to ask the question here. Think and then sign me here.

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks for the reference. So,let me think about it.

Comment: $\large +1 \;\land \;\checkmark$